# How do they make apps that tweak the registry

Tags: windows, regedit

Yesterday I've read something about putting other menus when you right click on your desktop. By editing the registry through regedit.exe.
Today or tomorrow there will be an app that will do this automatically.
How do they make this kinds of applications? Can you give me some idea on what programming language do they use. And how do they do it. Please enlighten me

Comment: Maybe StackOverflow will have more insight into how the programs are actually coded/written to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to get to deep into the coding aspect, an easy way would be to write the changes you want to a plaintext file, save it as a .reg, and then apply it to the registry, although as it was mentioned, there are developer functions for that

Answer (score 2):

Most applications on Windows are programmed in C++ or C#.

As for editing the registry, Microsoft has a set of function calls the developer can use to access the registry.